# Outlook Helpdesk plugin

Tags: microsoft-outlook, plugins

I run a small Helpdesk of 4 agents. We get roughly 60 - 100 tickets per day. Currently, we get tickets as emails in a couple different shared inboxes (using Outlook 2013 to manage emails) and manually log each email as a ticket in Sharepoint. The problem with this is that it is a long process to manually log each ticket.

We've looked at official helpdesk systems (osTicket, Zendesk, etc...) but we're seeing too many sacrifices to move to these.

So my suggestion is some sort of plugin that logs each email as a ticket, picks up on replies to update the ticket, generates metrics around tickets, etc...

Does anyone know of a plugin that can do this? I've looked at Dynamics CRM already.

Comment: Keep in mind you can implement Zendesk and keep using outlook just as you do today... Zendesk catches the inbound emails and generates tickets which it then forwards to the entire team. A team member can respond to the ticket via email and the customer receives the response as well as getting logged in ZD...  Long time user of shared email support before switching to desk.com and ultimately Zendesk.

Comment: Also check out help scout if you don't need all the ZD Bells and whistles. :  https://www.helpscout.net/zendesk-alternative/

Answer (score 0):

I think most helpdesk solutions switch the process such that the ticketing system takes control of the shared inbox and then manages notifications to the right people so email still goes out. [Request Tracker (RT)](http://bestpractical.com/rt), for example, watches any number of email addresses (like support@example.com) and routes incoming email to a queue. If the email is a new request, a ticket is created, if it's a response, it is appended to an existing ticket. All of this activity is communicated out to "watchers" on the ticket using a series of configurable notifications (emails).

Watchers on a ticket or queue still get email and, depending on their role (person requesting help or one of your staff), the email notifications can be different. The system keeps track of all sorts of metadata (all correspondence, dates and times of activity, status like open or resolved, etc.).

Depending on how heavily your users use mail, there are also extensions that allow you to change ticket values from email or parse incoming email for values and set fields on the ticket. This allows staff to work completely from email and still do things like update a status on a ticket from open to resolved.

Ticketing systems also manage metadata like "current owner" so your staff aren't accidentally working on the same ticket. RT also can show you a list of other tickets from a given requestor (based on email address) so you can see if a user has a recurring issue.

It sounds like you might want to look at some helpdesk systems and pick one that allows you to maintain much of your current workflow. Once you get things implemented you could look at additional features available in the product.